# How to listen to a script tag's onload event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<script id="me" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script
<script>
    var oB = document.getElementsById('me');
    me.onload = function(){
        alert('OK');
    }
</script>
```

Why `me.onload` is not triggered after the script is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

- a missing `>` at the end of the first line (you have written `</script` instead of `</script>`)
- there is no variable `me`: you have retrieved the script tag into a variable `oB`.

Thus, you can fix your code by change `me.onload = ...` to `ob.onload = ...`.

Moreoever, you should avoid using inlined declaration of event listeners such as `<script onload="...">`.

Last but not least, you should use `addEventListener` instead of `onxxx`: [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementsById`

`oB` instead of `me`

```
<script id="me" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script
<script>
    var oB=document.getElementById('me');
    oB.onload=function(){
        alert('OK')
    }
</script>
```

But this won't work either because me is already loaded like the other answer states.

Answer (score -1):

before you execute the alert codes, the script tag with id "me" is already downloaded, so despite the syntax error in your code, you can not get the alert.

you can simply use:

```
<script id="me" onload="alert('OK');"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```